# how to show image on page refresh in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

what i need

- i need to show image when user select particular event. consider add to favorite functionality.
- when user click on image data is store in array.
- then  user click particular image ,after reloading page  another image should be shown at that position.

js code

on dom ready

1. show image on particular clicked div.

   ```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     console.log(localStorage);
     if (localStorage.id!='')
     {

   var  image_url='/images/star1_phonehover.png';

     $('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + image_url + '")');
    }
     });
   ```
2. js code to set and get items

   ```
       function favaorite(sess_id,name,city,country,event_url,pointer)
       {

       /* clear storage  code*/
       //window.localStorage.clear();

       /* store imageurl in localstorage */
       var  imageUrl='/images/star1_phonehover.png';


       // Save data to the current local store//
       if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined' ) {
       console.log('Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.');
       }
       else
       {
       try {
       // Put the object into storage
       localStorage.setItem('id' ,JSON.stringify(sess_id));
       }
       catch (e)
       {
       if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
       {
            console.log('Quota exceeded!');//data wasn't successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
       }
       }
       try {
       // Put the object into storage
       localStorage.setItem('name' ,JSON.stringify(name));
       }
       catch (e)
       {
       if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
       {
            console.log('Quota exceeded!');//data wasn't successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
       }
       }
       try {
       // Put the object into storage
       localStorage.setItem('city',JSON.stringify(city));
       }
       catch (e)
       {
       if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
       {
           console.log('Quota exceeded!'); //data wasn't successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
       }
       }
       try
       {
       // Put the object into storage
       localStorage.setItem('country',JSON.stringify(country));
       }
       catch (e)
       {
       if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
       {
           console.log('Quota exceeded!'); //data wasn't successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
       }
       }
       try
       {
       // Put the object into storage
       localStorage.setItem('event_url',JSON.stringify(event_url));
       }
       catch (e)
       {
       if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
       {
              console.log('Quota exceeded!'); //data wasn't successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
       }
       }
       try
       {
       // Put the object into storage
       localStorage.setItem('imageUrl',JSON.stringify(imageUrl));
       }
       catch (e)
       {
       if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
       {
              console.log('Quota exceeded!'); //data wasn't successfully saved due to quota exceed so throw an error
       }
       }

       }


       /* fetch the data using from localstorage */
       var id= [];
       var name= [];
       var city = [];
       var country =[];
       var event_url= [];

       // Retrieve the object from storage
       //var id, city, country,event_url; 
       var id = localStorage.getItem('id');
       id = JSON.parse(id);
       console.log(id);

       var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
       name = JSON.parse(name);
       console.log(name);

       var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
       name = JSON.parse(name);

       var city = localStorage.getItem('city');
       city = JSON.parse(city);
       console.log(city);

       var country = localStorage.getItem('country');
       country = JSON.parse(country);
       console.log(country);

       var event_url = localStorage.getItem('event_url');
       event_url = JSON.parse(event_url);
       ///console.log(event_url);

       var image_url = localStorage.getItem('imageUrl');
       //event_url = JSON.parse(event_url);
       alert(image_url);
       //console.log(image_url);

       //console.log($(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.star'));
       if (id!='' )
       {
       $(pointer).closest('.evt_date').find('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
       $('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + image_url + '")');

       }




       }
   ```

Problem

- i have stored image in localstorage and trying load image on page refresh so ist applying on all div which div i have not clciked marke as favorite.
- here is snapshot of json data:

[image]

- in snapshot you could see localstorage only stores single json.
- i need to ask is localstorage don"t store whole data that i have clicked its hows recent data in localstorage.

  ```
     output should be
  ```

  - select particular data and store in localstorage in nested json string.
  - and on dom load or page refresh show particular on div whose id stored in localstorage.

    i have tried a  solution

    ```
            $(document).ready(function() {
           console.log(localStorage.id);
        if (localStorage.id==30301)
         {

        var  image_url='/images/star1_phonehover.png';
      $('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + image_url + '")');
        }

    });
    ```
  - then also it is applying image on all divs though it should apply on particular saved it of localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to show a 'star' next to items a user has 'favorited' and you want to store these favorites in local storage.

Ignoring your existing code, I'd use a strategy like this:

1) Save the id's for each favorited item into an array and store that in local storage

```
localStorage.setItem('favorites' ,JSON.stringify(arrayOfFavorites));
```

2) On dom ready, add an attribute to all the 'favorited' items. Note, to do this you'll need to add some identifying attribute to each dom node you care about. I assume you have something like `<div class='item' data-id='your-id'></div>`:

```
var list = getArrayFromLocalStorage('favorites');
list.forEach(function(id) {
  $('.item[data-id="' + id + '"').attr('favorite', '');
}
```

3) Finally, in your css, enable the background image for all `items` with the `favorite` attribute

```
item[favorite] {
   background-image: '/images/star1_phonehover.png'
}
```

Hopefully this strategy points you in the right direction.

Comment: i have also tried same logic  by checking in if  if (localStorage.id==30301) , but role problem by showing star on all divs , though it should be on only particular id of div.

Comment: $('.favourate_dextop').css('background-image', 'url("' + image_url + '")') like this

Comment: problem is like when dom ready image is applying on all div i want to apply only particular id of that div which id stored in localstoarge.

Comment: It sounds like you're tagging all the elements as 'favorited' and not just a subset of them. Without a jsfiddle I can't help much more.

Comment: one thing i just want to in snapshot  is localstorage store the data in single json ..i have cross checked in console. by localstorage it showing only single string..json